# Passing link value to ajax function onclick event

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

i have a link that contain some data

eg

```
<li><a href="" onclick="getcategory(this);"><?php echo $result22['category']; ?></a></li>
```

i want this link to pass this `$result22['category'];` value to the ajax function
 am trying this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getcategory(cat)
{
var id = cat.value;
alert("hi" + id);
}
</script>
```

but its shows hi undefined in alert box

what am doing wrong ?
am not getting correct value of `$result22['category'];` in alert box

Comment: What's the result of `alert(cat)`?

Comment: url of the page 
but i dont want the url i want the value of '$result22['category'];'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `cat` is an `a` element, it won't have a `value` property. Use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent) or `innerText` (or `innerHTML` if there could be child elements):

```
function getcategory(cat) {
    var id = cat.textContent;
    alert("hi" + id);
}
```

It's generally only form controls that have a value property (the `input` element for example).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this?

```
<li><a href="" onclick="getcategory('<?= $result22['category']; ?>');"><?php echo $result22['category']; ?></a></li>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getcategory(content) {
  alert(content);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<li><a href="" id=<?php echo $result22['category']; ?> onclick="getcategory(this.id);"><?php echo $result22['category']; ?></a></li>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  function getcategory(cat)
  {
       //var id = cat.value;
       alert("hi" + cat);
  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend you output into the function if your are not using a separate javascript file to bind the onClick handler that is :

```
<li>
    <a href="" onclick="getcategory('<?php echo $result22['category']; ?>');">
        <?php echo $result22['category']; ?>
    </a>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="" onclick="getcategory(this); return false;">hello</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getcategory(ele) {
        var id = ele.innerHTML;
        alert(id);
    }
</script>
```